# how can I user one Report Viewer for different RDLC/Reports

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc

I want to use one reportviewer control for all rdlc file.all rdlc reports have some common and some uncommon parameters or search criteria.

anybody know how can I achieve this ? I don't want different reportviewer control for different reports.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set every aspect of your ReportViewer control at runtime.

To set the correct rdlc file:

```
YourReportViewerControl.LocalReport.ReportPath = <path to your rdlc file>
```

To add parameters at runtime:

```
Dim parA As New ReportParameter("parA", "this is A")
Dim parB As New ReportParameter("parB", "this is B")

YourReportViewerControl.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {parA, parB})
```

To add datasources at runtime:

```
YourReportViewerControl.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("yourDataSourceName", YourDataSource))
```

So you can set only the right parameters/datasets for the rdlc sent to ReportViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Code below can be used to use multiple rdlc files with a single report viewer.

//Add this code to embed a report at runtime

```
    reportViewer1.Reset();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ReportViewer.Report2.rdlc";
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

//reportViewer1--> A Report Viewer Control

//ReportViewer --> Name of the solution

//Report2.rdlc --> Name of the report

Comment: Please keep in mind that I have different parameters for each reports.so this will not work for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Your\report\path.rdlc";
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources[x] = "datasourceID";
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh(); 
in Asp.net

for windows form

 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Your\report\path.rdlc";
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources[x] = "datasourceID";
            ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```